# Regex pattern to remove unknown number of repeating specified string at the beginning of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to find a regex pattern that will match a repeating string of words separated by white space, but only if it's at the beginning of a larger string.

```
"Copy of Copy of Copy of This is my String"
```

I want to get rid of all the "Copy of " strings, so the result is:

```
"This is my String"
```

The "Copy of " can occur an unknown number of times.  Want to get rid of all of them, but only if they start at the beginning of the string.

I tried: `\G(\Copy of )( (?=\1 ))?`  This was from an example I saw but couldn't figure out how to modify it to work as I want.

Comment: Did you try googling for javascript and regex and reading to understand, rather than reading for the exact example?

Comment: ... did you try replace?

Comment: Sounds like homework to me if you have to use regex. Read your notes and learn to search for the info - it'll be the most important skill you'll learn.

Comment: Also, you need to clarify what "repeating strings" means. Is an individual character a string? In "A A A x" would be a repetitive "A " string. But in "AAA x", would "A" also be a repetitive string?

Comment: So, if you have "AAAAx", then the "AAAA" part could e.g. be a repetition of string "AA" (2 times)? Or does a string have to end on a non-word character? Whitespace?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression)

Comment: The question appears to be about removing a repeated group rather than accessing a capturing group per se.

Comment: You first mention removing a 'repeating' string, but later state the string can occur 'an unknown number of times'. Does that include a single occurrence as in `Copy of This is my String`?

Comment: Looks like Windows automatically-generated filenames to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the [RegExp reference on
MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).
This explains how RegExp patterns in JavaScript work.

- For 'beginning of string', use `^`.
- For 'zero or more times', use `*`.
- For 'one or more times', use `+`.

Either of the last two will work in this case.

Putting it all together:

```js
var re = /^(Copy of )*/;
console.log('Copy of Copy of Copy of This is my String'.replace(re, ''));
console.log('Copy of This is my String'.replace(re, ''));
console.log('This is my String'.replace(re, ''))
```

Comment: No worries, but please have a good read through that documentation before asking more questions :-). Even if you don't get it right away, it should help point you in the right direction for further research.

Answer (score 2):

To match repetitive strings (without knowing the exact string), you need to use [capturing groups and backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html).

Depending on the definition of 'string', there are multiple solutions, e.g.:

- Any character sequence: `^(.+?)\1+`

  - Matches e. g. "AAA" of "AAA B", "AA" of "AA AA B", whitespace
- Character sequence ending on whitespace: `^(.+?\s)\1+`

  - Matches e. g. "AA AA " of "AA AA B", whitespace
- Character sequence ending on word boundary: `^(.+?\b)\1+`

  - Doesn't match whitespace. This is probably what you want.

If you want to match the remaining, non-repetitive part of the string, simply add a second capturing group `(.*)` to the above regex:

```js
// Get the repeated word:
console.log('Copy of Copy of Copy of This is my String'.match(/^(.+?\b)\1+(.*)/)[1]);
            
// Get the remaining string:
console.log('Copy of Copy of Copy of This is my String'.match(/^(.+?\b)\1+(.*)/)[2]);
```

Explanation: `^` matches the start of our string, the capturing group `(.+?\b)` matches any character one or more times followed by a word boundary and allows us to reference to its match later via `\1`. Since we are looking for one or more repetitions, we try to match against `\1+`.

I recommend https://regex101.com/#javascript or similar tools to better understand and explore regex.

Comment: I think you want `.+?`, otherwise it fails on 'Copy of Copy of Copy of Copy of Copy of This is my String'.

Comment: @FizzyTea Good find, `.+?` produces more plausible results.